# Mutual information for markov chain identity qeustion

Tags: markov-process, entropy, mutual-information

given that:
$$A-B-C-D \space\space  markov \space chain$$
We know that:
$$ I(A;C|D) = H(C|D)-H(C|A,D)$$
but does it also say that:
$$ H(C|A,D)=H(C|D) \space \space from \space the \space markovian?$$
does this move legit?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it does not.

As you correctly pointed out,

$$ I(A;C|D) = H(C|D)-H(C|A,D),$$

and so

$$H(C|A,D)=H(C|D)$$ would imply that $$I(A;C|D) = 0.$$

It's easy to give a counterexample though.

Say that $A$ is a random fair heads/tails coin flip (with entropy 1 in bits), $B = A$, $C= B$, and $D = tails$. Note that this is indeed a Markov chain. In this case, clearly $D$ contains no information at all, and 
$$
I(A;C|D) = I(A;C) = H(A) - H(A | C) = 1 - 0 \gneq 0.
$$.

Comment: Great!, thanks, I was thinking that given the markov chain, the uncertinty in $C$ would only be affected by the previous member of the chain which is $D$, which would imply that the entropy $H(C|,A,D)$ would not depend on $A$. what am I assuming wrong here?

Comment: "the previous member of the chain which is $D$" - not that it matters much (the question is symmetric in $A$ and $D$, and you don't need $B$ at all), but is $D$ the *previous* member? I thought it's the *next*. In any case, if $X \rightarrow Y \rightarrow Z$ form a MC, then the only thing to say is that $I(X; Z|Y) = 0$.

Comment: (continued) Think about the case of $X \rightarrow Y \rightarrow Z$, where $X$ is a dice roll, $Y$ is a pair of results of the previous dice roll and a new one, and $Z$ is a prize that is given if the sum of the rolls is greater than 7. Clearly, if you know $X$ (the first dice roll) and $Z$ (whether the prize was given), the uncertainty about the second dice roll decreases .

Comment: No problem. All the best.